# Design breaking while using flex with dimension in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Using `import {dimension} from 'react-native'` and `flex:1` at the same time in css style and for some devices design got broken when there is input field present inside the js. CSS is so simple that's it should not be broken

```
MainContainer: {
    height : Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width : Dimensions.get('window').width,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 1
}
```

and moreover there is slight 1 px blank space for some android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier when I have started coding with `react-native`  I have faced the same issue while using the same css style.
You should read the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) first carefully to get idea about `flex`.

> `flex` will define how your items are going to “*fight*” over the
> available space along your primary axis. Most of the time you will
> want your app container to be `flex:1` to take all of the screen
> height. Space will be divided according to each element flex property.
> In the following example the red, yellow and the green views are all
> children in the container view that got `flex:1.` The red view got
> `flex:1` , the yellow view got `flex:2` and the green view got
> `flex:3` . 1+2+3=6 which means that red view will get 1/6 of the
> space, the yellow 2/6 of the space and the red 3/6 of the space. I
> think you got it…

To get more clear idea about the above lines please refer to this [medium.com](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/the-full-react-native-layout-cheat-sheet-a4147802405c)'s [post](https://medium.com/wix-engineering/the-full-react-native-layout-cheat-sheet-a4147802405c)

And basically we don't use `dimension` while developing app using `react-native` .

```
MainContainer: {
   height: '100%',
   width: '100%',
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
}
```

This will be enough to design the main container. Also If you are using Input field then I will suggest to use `scrollView`

I think My answer will help you.